# Problemas para importar pacote no Python3 em sistema de filas de cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x

O pacote skopt (https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/install.html) foi instalado em um cluster que eu uso.

Quando executo o código em python diretamente no terminal (ou seja, terminal de cluster), nenhum problema ocorre e o código funciona conforme o esperado.

No entanto, quando simplesmente coloco o comando para executar o código em um arquivo de sistema de fila PBS (por exemplo, python3 ./code.py), não consigo carregar o pacote instalado e recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
 Traceback (última chamada mais recente):
     Arquivo "./code.py", linha 22, em <module>
        from skopt import gp_minimize
 ModuleNotFoundError: Nenhum módulo chamado 'skopt'
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia de como resolver o problema?

Se eu precisar fornecer mais informações, me informem, por gentileza.

ps1: o pacote foi instalado no diretório /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt.

Comment: quando você faz um pip3 list  aparece o nome do pacote instalado ?

Comment: Você usa um ambiente virtual para executar o código? Meu palpite é que o Python que você executa diretamente no terminal e o Python que é executado pelo sistema de filas são instalações diferentes. Ou então é alguma configuração/variáveis de ambiente que o sistema de filas carrega e atrapalha a forma como Python encontra os pacotes. Pra saber ao certo só testando.

Comment: @JhonathanWolff Sim, o pacote aparece!

Comment: @jfaccioni existe alguma forma de eu carregar o pacote instalado no sistema PBS? Eu pensei em "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:[$HOME]/.usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt", mas acho que estou fazendo algo de errado

Comment: @EmersonPL não conheço o sistema PBS, mas acredito que adicionar a pasta `site-packages` ao `$PYTHONPATH` faz com que o Python encontre todos os pacotes instalados lá dentro. Se não funcionar, deve ser outro problema.

Comment: @jfaccioni uma dúvida: se o pacote foi instalado na pasta "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt", a forma de exportar seria "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:[$HOME]/.usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt" ou algo diferente? eu preciso declarar o que é PYTHONPATH? Eu coloquei esse arquivo "export" e o erro continua. Talvez o comando export esteja escrito da forma errada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso você consiga executar um código em Python em que consiga carregar pacotes normalmente executando o script diretamente no terminal, mas que não consiga fazer isso indiretamente em um arquivo de sistema de filas .PBS (que acuse que os pacotes não estão instalados), siga as seguintes etapas:

1. Descubra em qual diretório o pacote foi instalado (no meu caso estava em
   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/")
2. Antes de chamar a execução do seu código em Python no arquivo de filas .PBS (e.g., "python3 ./code.py"), use um comando "export" baseado no diretório em que o pacote foi instalado, no meu exemplo utilizei o comando:
   "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages".

Exemplo de arquivo .pbs para executar o código "code.py":

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N nome_do_job
#PBS -e arquivo_de_erro
#PBS -o arquivo_de_output
#PBS -q nome_da_fila
#PBS -l nodes=x:ppn=y

### o pacote "teste" foi instalado na pasta "usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"

### o comando abaixo carrega o pacote:
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages

### o comando abaixo executa o código em python "code.py" que importa o pacote "teste"  
python3 ./code.py
```

Em que no arquivo "code.py" é importado o pacote "teste". Exemplo:

```
import teste

... código em python ...
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça detalhes adicionais em sua resposta. Como está escrita atualmente, é difícil entender sua solução.

Comment: @Comunidade por gentileza, veja se com as alterações, a descrição ficou melhor.

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.